# Django Break Queryset into sub querysets based on param

Tags: python, django

I am looking for a "group_by" like functionality that will allow me to separate a django queryset into multiple querysets, grouped by a parameter (in my case, a date). I have a working solution, but I know it could be greatly improved if I knew a bit more about the more advanced functions.

Here is my current (ugly) code below, to give you an idea of what I am specifically looking to do.

```
class ClassesListView(ListView):
    model = Class
    context_object_name = 'classes'
    template_name = 'classes/ClassesListTemplate.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(ClassesListView, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(start_datetime__gte = timezone.localtime(timezone.now()))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context_data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        qs = self.object_list
        querysets = []

        for i in range (0, 7):
            _date = timezone.localtime(timezone.now()) + timezone.timedelta(days=i)
            _qs = qs.filter(start_datetime__date = _date.date())
            querysets.append(
                {
                    'date' : _date,
                    'qs' : _qs
                }
            )

        context_data['querysets'] = querysets

        return context_data
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So you want this to be one query where you get 7 rows each with a date and one result?

Comment: I am looking for a query that will output a list of querysets, segmenting the original qs by a given param.

Comment: You can try writing your own model manager. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-model-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

you can use groupby from
[itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)
example

```
query_sets =  l = [{'date': "2020-04-23 10:57:45", 'qs': 2}, 
                   {'date': "2020-04-23 10:52:45", 'qs': 3}, 
                   {'date': "2020-04-23 10:58:45", 'qs': 8}, 
                   {'date': "2020-04-23 10:57:45", 'qs': 3}]
```

output

```
query_sets                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[35]: 
[{'date': '2020-04-23 10:57:45', 'qs': 2},
 {'date': '2020-04-23 10:52:45', 'qs': 3},
 {'date': '2020-04-23 10:58:45', 'qs': 8},
 {'date': '2020-04-23 10:57:45', 'qs': 3}]
```

like you see the list it's not sorted

```
import itertools

def sort_and_group(iterable, key=None): 
      """Group sorted `iterable` on `key`.""" 
    return itertools.groupby(sorted(iterable, key=key), key=key)


for k, v in sort_and_group(query_sets, lambda x: x['date']): print(k, list(v))


2020-04-23 10:52:45 [{'date': '2020-04-23 10:52:45', 'qs': 3}]
2020-04-23 10:57:45 [{'date': '2020-04-23 10:57:45', 'qs': 2}, {'date': '2020-04-23 10:57:45', 'qs': 3}]
2020-04-23 10:58:45 [{'date': '2020-04-23 10:58:45', 'qs': 8}]
```

i'm little confuse if that what you expected
i hope that the solution